# Prevent jQuery animation at page reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, session-state

I've made a cute effect of me being scaled and translated to a corner of the page before the essential information gets displayed. Now, i just realized that a user will be forced to see it EVERY times he/she reload the page.

I wonder how i can do about to only run the animation on the first visit since the last restart of the browser, i.e. if the user arrives from an other domain than my own.

If that's too complicated, i'd like to run the animation once and then somehow inform the browser never to run it again. or at least not in, say, one day.

Since i'm not to use cookies for a certain, illogical but unavoidable reason, i'll try to apply the session state. So, i made the following changes to the code.

Config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var execute = 0; // 0 - no animation, 1 - full length animation
$("div.mainInfo img")
  .delay(400 * execute)
  .fadeIn(1000 * execute);
  ...
}
```

Page_Load:

```
Session["hazaa"] = "shazoo";
if(IsPostBack)
{
  if(Session["hazaa"] == "shazoo";
    DoTheCoolStuffToAffectJQueryOnTheClient(0);
}
```

So, if hazaa indeed is shazoo i want to change the jQuery execution flag but then... Exactly, how do i do that?! The flag is annoying me anyway, because every second time i upload the work, i forget to turn it on, so it's a static zero **every** time. So, if it's got to go in order to allow for *DoTheCoolStuffToAffectJQueryOnTheClient(0)* call work, i won't cry.

Comment: as cookie monster says, COOOOKIES

Comment: I would hope that now `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` can be used over cookies. Cookies are evil.

Comment: @Lavabeams So would i. Any suggestions on how to extend the code above to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use session or local storage for what you're trying to accomplish.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

session storage will only last until browser restart and local storage is persistent lasting until the client clears it

to use all you have to do is on animation complete store a value
ie.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("animeRan", 'yes');
```

then anywhere on your other pages as long as the are in the same domain you can access it using

```
sessionStorage.getItem("animeRan");
```

and remove it anytime using

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("animeRan");
```

Here is a site you can check for browser compatibility/support and more info on web storage

http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: Local storage has limited browser support, and sessions would require some server-side programming. Not sure if that is a problem though...

Comment: It's all client side.. You don't need server-side programming for this.  It's DOM storage

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, wasn't reading properly, read "session" and immediately though of server sessions. Still, there will be limited support for it.

Comment: It seems that the support is quite good, according to caniuseit so i think i'll go with this one. The only part i'm unclear about is how to execute removeItem() just **BEFORE** the user closes the browser (or leaves the site to another domain).

Comment: Oh.. if you are using session storage you don't need to even call that as it will do it by itself. `Session storage is tied to the life of the session. Which means until you close the window or browser. Local Storage is stored indefinitely - until user clears their browsers storage.`

Comment: @wirey Now i've checked it and apparently cookies are a no-go so, as you suggested i'll have to rely on session state. I change the web.config file to include <sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState> but i'm not clear on how to communicate the state to the JS on the client. Please see the updated source code in the original post for details. Mucho thanko, BTW.

Comment: `sessionStorage` lasts for the session of the browser, `localStorage` lasts until removed (browser cleared or removed by js etc)

Comment: @KonradViltersten What I suggested is all client side so you just have to use `sessionStorage' in your javascript where you need it.  Example once the animation is complete the store an item in sessionStorage so you are able to access it on your other pages.  You don't have to do anything on the server side

Comment: It worked as charm and it was a perfect answer because it opens for me to much easy to a lot of stuff i've done the hard way, up to now. Mucho thanko! However, i have one more catch. Since sessionStorage object resides in the global window object, why don't we refer to it as *window.sessionStorage*? It looks a bit like an old C code when one just throws in method calls without a specification to the instance they are in. What do others think?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to what [wirey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385672/wirey) has said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726035/261564).
Here is a code example if you are unsure on how it actually is used.

You would use [`sessionStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) like follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("animationDone") !== null) {
    $("div.mainInfo img")
      .delay(400 * execute)
      .fadeIn(1000 * execute);
      ...
      sessionStorage.setItem("animationDone", "done");
   }
}
```

This is saved to the browsers [`sessionStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) and has nothing to do with server side.

If you really need to remove it yourself `sessionStorage.removeItem("animationDone");`

The [`sessionStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) will expire when the browsers session is ended. E.g: closing the browser etc.

Comment: I might have misunderstood both you Lavabeams and @wirey since i was sure we talked about **server side** session state management. You are actually talking about the **client side** version, which, of course, is definitely to be preferred. Thanks - i'll try out that code right after my coffee.

Comment: Yes `DOMStorage` is all client side :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cookie when the first animation has completed. Then you read that cookie on every page load, to see if the animation has been run recently. A small drawback would be that user who don't accept cookies will still see it everytime, but I believe they are quite few.

For jQuery, there are [plugins](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to make it easier for you to manage cookies.

Using the above plugin, I'd say your code would be something like this:

```
$(function () {
   if (!$.cookie("animationRun")) {
      $("#some-selector").animate(... , function () {
         // Let the cookie expire after one day
         $.cookie("animationRun", true, { expires: 1 });
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... But setting up cookies lead to the users being forced to click in an "alert()-thingy", doesn't it. It sort of kills the buzz... Can that be avoided? HTML5 maybe has something for it?

Comment: HTML 5 does have something for it actually. Look up HTML5 cross-document messaging.

Comment: Yeah, there is the EU cookie law that was introduced a few months ago, and if you want to obey that, I agree that it would somewhat kill the buzz. There are a couple of ways to do this using HTML5-techniques, but beware of the limited browser support. Not sure if that is a problem though?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a cookie and check if that cookie is present before playing the animation.

One drawback here is, that users, who don't accept your cookies will still always see the animation.

Comment: You could set it up to be dependent on cookies. In other words, if you can set a cookie, then you show the animation and set the cookie to make it stop. If you can't set a cookie, then you don't do the animation. That way, people who disable cookies just won't see it at all.

Comment: @Chris Pratt "people who disable cookies just won't see it at all" Which wouldn't be a valid solution for most of my customers…

Comment: Why not? I don't mean they won't see the element at all; they just won't see all the fancy-smancy animation of the element. Animations are cute, but most people are going to grow tired of it quick. A growing number of people are disabling cookies due to privacy concerns, so showing an animation every time to this population is going to send them running for the hills. It's not a bad compromise, if you can't disable it for them after one time, you don't animate at all.